# spring data @query 'cached' table?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

**App entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class App implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "app_alloweduser",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="apps_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="allowedusers_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<User> allowedusers = new HashSet<>(); 
}
```

I try to write my own query as such.

```
@Query("SELECT app FROM App app WHERE (:department is null or app.department = :department) and "
        + "(:platform is null or app.platform = :platform) and "
        + "(:appName is null or lower(app.appName) LIKE CONCAT('%',lower(:appName),'%')) and "
        + "(app.id in (SELECT b.apps_id FROM allowedusers b where b.allowedusers_id = :loginid))")
Page<App> findAllAllowed(@Param("department") Department department,
                         @Param("platform") Platform platform,
                         @Param("appName") String appName,
                         @Param("loginid") Long loginid,
                         Pageable pageable);
```

**Error**: `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: allowedusers is not mapped`

I have tried `app_alloweduser` also and it too throws the same error that it can't map. The table `APP_ALLOWEDUSER`, which is what I am interested in is verified to be there though. So I am wondering what is going on here.

**Some background**
The table `app_alloweduser` has 2 column, `app_id` & `user_id`. I will first have to retrieve a list of `app_id` given a `user_id`. Then return all `app` from this list of `app_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `FROM allowedusers` by `FROM app.allowedusers`

Comment: Tried this and it maps to `User` entity, which is not quite what I want. I want to be able to access the table `APP_ALLOWEDUSER`

Answer (score 0):

There is no alloweduser entity only App and User. Try to use join instead.

```
@Query("SELECT app FROM App app join User u WHERE (:department is null or app.department = :department) and "
        + "(:platform is null or app.platform = :platform) and "
        + "(:appName is null or lower(app.appName) LIKE CONCAT('%',lower(:appName),'%')) and "
        + "(u.allowedusers_id = :loginid))")
```

UPDATE:
change `u.allowedusers_id = :loginid` to `u.id = :loginid`.
You don't have the table in HQL. Of course you can introduce a new entity if you need for the `APP_ALLOWEDUSER`

Comment: The `User` table doesn't have a column `allowedusers_id`. I would definitely need a way to access to this table `APP_ALLOWEDUSER`. Is it possible? It stores the `app_id` & `user_id`, on which user has access to which app. Both the `App` & `User` table has no such 'rights information'.

Comment: The updated answer will return all `App`. It only verifies that the supplied `loginid` is a valid record on the `User` table. It doesn't achieve the 'filter' according to 'rights' that I would like to implement. I guess I would need to create a separate entity `APP_ALLOWEDUSER`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can access the table via `a.allowedusers`

Given the following declaration or particularly this line,

```
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="allowedusers_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
```

I can access the database equivalent of `app_alloweduser.allowedusers_id` using `a.allowedusers.id` on JPQL.

```
@JoinTable(name = "app_alloweduser",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="apps_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="allowedusers_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<User> allowedusers = new HashSet<>();
```

**Final Query**

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM App a JOIN a.allowedusers au WHERE au.id = :loginid AND "
            + "(:department is null or a.department = :department) AND "
            + "(:platform is null or a.platform = :platform) AND "
            + "(:appName is null or lower(a.appName) LIKE CONCAT('%',lower(:appName),'%'))")
Page<App> findAllAllowed(@Param("department") Department department,
                         @Param("platform") Platform platform,
                         @Param("appName") String appName,
                         @Param("loginid") Long loginid,
                         Pageable pageable);
```